# Import project into Android-Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I have been given an Android project created in Eclipse which I need to port to Android-Studio.

I'm using the most up-to-date version of the Android-Studio (0.2.6 build 130.795381) which includes a bundled gradle distribution (version 1.7).

I followed the instructions written [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)
and asked the guy that handed me the project to provide me with the products of this procedure.

So he did and sent me a "build.gradle" file which suppose to make the import possible.

I opened the Android-Studio and tried to import the project (using any of the possible options) and it failed due to:
[image]

I tried to download gradle version 1.6 and choose it by selecting the "local gradle distribution" option, but this time it fails due to:
[image]

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve on my own.

Needed to alter the build.gradle file a bit so the buildscript->dependencies will hold this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
```

and not:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
```

Then used the "local gradle distribution" option with the 1.6 version I downloaded and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

just use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'` in order to stay up to date with the gradle plugin.